# List storing pointers or "plain object"

Tags: c++11

I am designing a class which tracks the user manipulations in a software in order to restore previous application states (i.e. CTRL+Z/CTRL+Y). I symply wanted to clarify something about performances.

I am using the `std::list` container of the STL. This list is not meant to contain really huge objects, but a significant number. Should I use pointers or not?

For instance, here is the kinds of objects which will be stored:

```
struct ImagesState
{
    cv::Mat first;
    cv::Mat second;
};

struct StatusBarState
{
    std::string notification;
    std::string algorithm;
};
```

For now, I store the whole thing under the form of `struct` pointers, such as:

```
std::list<ImagesStatee*> stereoImages;
```

I know (I think) that `new` and `delete` operators are time consuming, but I don't want to encounter a stack overflow with "plain object". Is it a bad design?

Comment: Pointers are generally not needed except for polymorphism. Store values (object instances, not pointers to them). And remember that `std::vector` should be the "default container".

Comment: With that said, *if* you opt for pointers anyway, use the new smart pointers that was introduced in C++11.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude 'smart pointers' yes for safety purposes.

Comment: "Pointers are generally not needed except for polymorphism" is definitly wrong. Even a "Hello World" program.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude And sharing resources. That is one of use cases when it's pretty impossible to out without pointers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using a list, i would suggest not to use the pointer. The list items are on the heap anyway and the pointer just adds an unnecessary layer of indirection.

If you are after performance, using std::list is most likely not the best solution. Using std::vector might boost your performance significantly since the objects are better for your caches.
Even in an vector, the objects would lie on the heap and therefore the pointer are not needed (they would even harm you more than with a list). You only have to care about them if you make an array on your stack.

like so:

```
Type arrayName[REALLY_HUGE_NUMBER]
```

Comment: 'If you are after performance, using std::list' Yes, I know, but I heard that list show better performance for insertion. Anyway, I do not need to insert object anymore. I am going with vector.

Comment: ' The list items are on the heap anyway and the pointer just adds an unnecessary layer of indirection.' If I am not using pointers, does it call my object constructor when I push_back or the move constructor?

Comment: It depends if you have an rvalue or lvalue. If you do something like:
vector.push_back(ObjectType(param1,...,paramn));
It will most likely call the move constructor. If you want to save that call you can call 
vector.emplace_back(param1,...,paramn);
That will construct the object in the vector. No copy or move needed afterwards.